# Helm3 : Overriding image tag value

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I was trying to override the image tag in Helm3 using upgrade command by setting the variable at command line but it did not work. Has someone tried this feature in Helm3. 
Stuck for last couple of days, would be helpful to know your views.

Deployment manifest file looks like this:-

> ```
>     containers:
>    - image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{.Values.image.tag}}
>      imagePullPolicy: Always
> ```

Executing this command from command line:-

```
> helm upgrade resources-dev resources --set image.tag=72615 --dry-run --debug
```

does not override image tag value from 72626 to 72615

```
 containers:
  - image: aksresourcesapi.azurecr.io/microservicesinitiative:72626
    imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Deployment file
[image]

Command Results:-
helm upgrade resources-dev resources --set image.tag=72615 --reuse-values
[image]
Command Results of 
helm upgrade resources-dev resources --set-string image.tag=72615 
[image]

Comment: Under the text that says "deployment file" there's an image of some sort.  Can you replace this with the actual text of your YAML files?  (Try to avoid pasting screen shots of editors or terminal windows into SO questions if you can.)

Comment: I have observed two things from checking different examples in https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/. I'm not sure they are the reason for the problem. Try adding quotes, and leaving a space between `{{` and `.Values...` So replace the image line in your deployment file for:
`image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is identified, it's not with a --set flag but with the kind of directory structure I have for charts.

[image]

while executing the command

> helm upgrade resources-dev resources --set image.tag=72615

one level up where resources (charts) folder is, it looks for image.tag in "Values.yaml" file of resources folder and not the "Values.yaml" file of backend folder and thus the tags are not replaced.

By executing the below command with **backend.imge.tag** worked
helm upgrade resources-dev resources --install --set backend.image.tag=72615

Answer (score 1):

You should specify to helm that it is a string value. It is done with `--set-string` flag.

Also use `--reuse-values` in order to reuse the last release’s values and merge in any overrides from the command line via — set and -f

Executing the following command will solve the problem:

```
helm upgrade resources-dev resources --reuse-values --set-string image.tag=72615 --dry-run --debug
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, It did not override the values. On execution, it returned the below results:-

helm upgrade resources-dev resources --set-string image.tag=72615 --dry-run --debug

USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
image:
  tag: "72615"

COMPUTED VALUES:
  image:
    repository: aksresourcesapi.azurecr.io/microservicesinitiative
    tag: "72626"

Comment: In a User supplied values, it shows the changes but in the manifest file it does not pick up. The last line shows it still did not pick the value.

Comment: Executed this command and shared the results by adding more clarity to the main post.

Comment: did you found any workaround on set values of image?

Comment: Thanks `--set-string` works very nicely

Answer (score 0):

-set deployment.image.tag=  should be like this